# Installing python3 on Docker is failing

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I want a ubuntu container with python3 installed.
The apt-get install python3 returns the below error,

```
Setting up python3.6-minimal (3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.12) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 143, in compile
    importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 113, in _write_atomic
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-36.pyc.140337705268704'
dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.6-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I just tried a basic ubuntu image,

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
```

I event tried ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 versions. I get the same issue. Please help.

I came across help on internet. I tried

```
dpkg --configure -a 

apt upgrade 

apt-get install python3
```

I get the same issue. Please help

These commands were working a few months before